# How to operate in a directory within a directory in bash

Tags: bash, for-loop, directory

I'm working on taking contents from a directory into it's parent directory, all while working in another directory. If each directory is a layer, I'm trying to copy contents from a 3rd layer into the 2nd layer, then remove that 3rd layer. So far I have:

```
for d in "$layer1"/*; do

    temp=$(removespaces "$d")

    layer2=$(removeExtension "$temp")

    cp -r "$d" "$layer2"

    rm -r "$d"

    for dir in "$layer2"/*; do

        cp "$dir" "$layer2"

        rmdir "$dir" #This is the third layer(directory)
    done

done
```

The beginning of the 1st for loop is just renaming the directory with some functions I declare earlier, no problems there.

How can I copy the contents of this 3rd layer in the 2nd layer?

Comment: To rename a directory use `mv`, not `cp` followed by `rm`.

Comment: BTW, keep in mind that when you do `for d in "$layer1"/*`, if `layer1='foo'`, then you get something like `d='foo/bar'`. Thus, with `for d2 in "$d1"/*`, you get a `d2` like `foo/bar/baz`. Since these are fully-qualified paths, you don't need to do anything at all to be able to work with them.

Comment: Beyond that, though, it's a little tricky to tell what you're doing here. Could you edit this to provide a [mcve]? An example that creates the old names (and defines or removes dependencies like `removespaces` and `removeExtension`, so we can actually run it ourselves and see what fails), would be a lot easier to speak to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last `cp` needs to copy the individual files, not the directory as a whole.

```
cp "$dir"/* "$layer2"
```

But you can do this whole thing more simply using `mv`, and use two wildcards in the pathname to get the 3rd level.

```
for d in "$layer1"/*; do
    temp=$(removespaces "$d")
    layer2=$(removeExtension "$temp")
    mkdir -p "$layer2"
    mv "$d"/*/* "$layer2"
    rmdir "$d"
done
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot for the clarification, sorry if it was a bit hard to understand. I'll for sure make my questions more clear in the future.

Comment: I always recommend using `mv -n` or `mv -i` in cases like this, in case there's a name conflict (the default is that it'll silently and irreversibly overwrite one of the files).